# How to use server side includes / SHTML?

Tags: html, shtml

Can any one plz guide me how to use **SHTML** in **vs code**.
I am trying to use this shtml because of includes but am getting rid of this ,am not getting how to create this and include the header and footer in all the files .

I need to know how to use **SHTML** in **VS CODE editor** and need to know how to include the header and footer .

so please if any one knows how it works please guide me that would help me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's an element of "rtfm" here (read the [dang] manual), but check this out, it should help you.
[AsrVision - Footers and Headers in SHTML](http://www.asrvision.com/web-design-tutorials/headers-footersn-in-shtml.htm)

(Near the bottom of the page, Step 3, is what you need.)